# Data bind to my application if write in other browser tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am working on an application where i used angular.js and node.js. The issue is that when i write something in other tab form then the same text is automatically gets bind to my application's first textbox.

I don't know what is the reason why this is happening. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use the same `ng-model` name for both inputs.
You need to use different names if they are not the same, example:

`<input ng-model="name">`

On second tab (html tabs?):
`<input ng-model="name2">`

Comment: Sorry, the issue is not this.. For an example i opened xyz.com in one tab and my application is on another tab and i write something in xyz.com textbox then this text reflect in my application's first textbox.